# Is it possible to embed href into a javascript function to open toggle?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using something that requires I use the following html code to open/close a toggle box:

```
<a href="#myToggle4" class="myToggle4">Open TogglePlus4 on this page</a>
```

I would like to know if I can trigger from a JavaScript function instead, or maybe how to embed the above code into a JavaScript function.

Something like:

```
function openstuff() {
    open myToggle4;
}
```

Comment: There is (most likely) a JS function bound to the click event of the `#myToggle4` element. Find what that is and call that function directly.

Comment: Thanks Juhana, I had to edit as the original code disappeared. I did look for that event but it is hidden away in the app I think. Tried looking at source but coudnt see. Maybe my question edit will help further.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, add an event listener for click event. Like this.

```
var toggle4a = document.getElementById("t4a");
var toggle4div = document.getElementById("toggle4");
toggle4a.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    console.log(toggle4div.hidden);
    if(toggle4div.hidden) 
        toggle4div.hidden = false;
    else
        toggle4div.hidden = true;
});
```

JSFiddle for the same in action - http://jsfiddle.net/u3ac8fx3/